# How to grab ffmpeg's output as binary and write it to a file on the fly such that video players can play it in real time?

Tags: c, shell, ffmpeg

I want to stream a RTSP-streaming device to a video player such as VLC but the catch is that, in between, the binary data needs to go through a custom high-speed serial link. I control what goes in this link from a C++ program.

I was happily surprised to see that the following line allowed me to watch the RTSP stream by just opening "out.bin" from VLC which was a good lead for fast and efficient binary transmission of the stream:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:password@X.X.X.X:554/h264Preview_01_main" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts out.bin
```

I already wondered how ffmpeg manages to allow VLC to read that file, while itself writing to it at the same time. Turns out I was right to wonder, see below.

I told myself I could make this command pipe its output to the standard output, and then in turn pipe the standard output to a file that I can read, (later, slice it, transmit the chunks and reconstruct it) and then write to an output file. However, this does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 188 //MPEG-TS packet size

int main()
{
    char *cmd = (char*)"ffmpeg -i \"rtsp://admin:password@X.X.X.X:554/h264Preview_01_main\" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts pipe:1 -loglevel quiet";
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *ptr, *file;

    file = fopen("./out.bin", "w");

    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Failed to open output file for writing, aborting");
       abort();
    }

    if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL) {
       printf("Writing RTSP stream to file...");

       while (!kbhit())
       {
            if(fread(&buf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, ptr) != 0)
            {
               fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, file);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("No data\n");
            }
       }
       pclose(ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to open pipe from ffmpeg command, aborting");
    }

    printf("End of program");

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Since VLC says "your input can't be opened" - whereas this works just fine:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:password@X.X.X.X:554/h264Preview_01_main" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts pipe:1 -loglevel quiet > out.bin
```

This is what ends up in the file after I close the program, versus the result of the command immediately above:
[image]

The file is always ~2kB regardless of how long I run the program: "No data" is shown repeatedly in the console output.

Why doesn't it work? If it is not just a bug, how can I grab the stream as binary at some point, and write it at the end to a file that VLC can read?

### Update

New code after applying Craig Estey's fix to my stupid mistake. The end result is that the MPEG-TS frames don't seem to shift anymore but the file writing stops partway into one of the first few frames (the console only shows a few ">" symbols and then stays silent, c.f. code).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 188                     // MPEG-TS packet size

int
main()
{
    char *cmd = (char *) "ffmpeg -i \"rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test.sdp\" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts pipe:1 -loglevel quiet";
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *ptr,
    *file;

    file = fopen("./out.ts", "w");

    if (!file) {
        printf("Failed to open output file for writing, aborting");
        abort();
    }

    if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL) {
        printf("Writing RTSP stream to file...");

        while(!kbhit()) {
            ssize_t rlen = fread(&buf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, ptr);
            if(rlen != 0)
            {
                printf(">");
                fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), rlen, file);
                fflush(file);
            }
        }
        pclose(ptr);
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to open pipe from ffmpeg command, aborting");
    }

    printf("End of program");

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

This can be tested on any computer with VLC and a webcam: open VLC, open capture device, capture mode directshow, (switch "play" for "stream"), next, display locally, select RTSP, Add, path=/test.sdp, next, transcoding=H264+MP3 (TS), replace rtsp://:8554/ with rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/ in the generated command line, stream.

To test that streaming is ok, you can just open a command terminal and enter "ffmpeg -i "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test.sdp" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts pipe:1 -loglevel quiet", the terminal should fill up with binary data.

To test the program, just compile, run, and open out.ts after the program has run.

Comment: What are the VLC commands you've tried?

Comment: I haven't tried any vlc command, I'm just opening the file by double clicking on it. It works with the output of the command piped to a file from bash, but not when I call the same piped command and pipe it to a file myself using popen() and fread(). So unless I'm mistaken VLC commands should not be necessary? I have noticed for example that in between the two files, there is a discrepancy in the length of MPEG TS frames from the location of the cursor on the image - which tells me the file is not written correctly? But how?

Comment: Updated the picture to illustrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `#include <conio.h>` is Windows only, we may conclude that you are using Windows.
(The rest of the code looks like Linux, so MinGW compiler is probably used...)

In Linux all files are binary files, but in Windows, the default file format is  text file.
I guess that the execution ends on the first EOF character (the issue may also be related to "new line" characters).

---

We have to open the files as **binary files**:

- Replace `file = fopen("./out.bin", "w");` with:

  ```
   file = fopen("./out.bin", "wb");
  ```
- Replace `ptr = popen(cmd, "r")` with:

  ```
   ptr = popen(cmd, "rb")
  ```

---

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 188                     // MPEG-TS packet size

int main()
{
    const char *cmd = "ffmpeg -i \"rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test.sdp\" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts pipe:1 -loglevel quiet";
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *ptr,
    *file;

    file = fopen("./out.ts", "wb");  //Open file as binary file

    if (!file) {
        printf("Failed to open output file for writing, aborting");
        abort();
    }

    if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "rb")) != NULL) {  //Open pipe as binary file
        printf("Writing RTSP stream to file...");

        while(!kbhit()) {
            ssize_t rlen = fread(&buf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, ptr);
            if(rlen != 0)
            {
                printf(">");
                fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), rlen, file);
                fflush(file);
            }
        }
        pclose(ptr);
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to open pipe from ffmpeg command, aborting");
    }

    printf("End of program");

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another stupid mistake in this very short code. I was looking someplace else so I'm glad you caught this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your total problem, but you're ignoring the return value from `fread`.

Pipe reads *can* return a *short* length. But, you're *always* writing `BUFSIZE` on output.

Here's the refactored code (I nop'ed the winX code because I'm on linux):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <conio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 188                     // MPEG-TS packet size

int
main()
{
    char *cmd = (char *) "ffmpeg -i \"rtsp://admin:password@X.X.X.X:554/h264Preview_01_main\" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts pipe:1 -loglevel quiet";
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *ptr,
    *file;

    file = fopen("./out.bin", "w");

    if (!file) {
        printf("Failed to open output file for writing, aborting");
        abort();
    }

    if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL) {
        printf("Writing RTSP stream to file...");

        while (1) {
#if 0
            if (kbhit())
                break;
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: this ignores the returned length and may write too much
#if 0
            if (fread(&buf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, ptr) != 0) {
                fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, file);
            }
            else {
                printf("No data\n");
            }
#else
            ssize_t rlen = fread(&buf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, ptr);
            if (rlen <= 0)
                break;

            fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), rlen, file);
#endif
        }
        pclose(ptr);
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to open pipe from ffmpeg command, aborting");
    }

    printf("End of program");

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

Comment: Dang it, this is such a stupid mistake - I was so focused on the rest I let it slide through my fingers; sorry and thanks. I don't think that's the whole solution as you say because I don't see any reason why the file writing should slow down or stop, but I'll try that after Christmas and let you know. Happy holidays

Comment: I have tested it and the bytes don't seem to shift anymore (thanks for spotting that) - but the file still cuts short for some reason (the program returns very quickly). I have updated my question with the new code and instructions on how to test it yourself if you are willing to :) Happy holidays